# How to use fs in Jupyter Lab extension/typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jupyter-lab

I tried to use fs to read a file in an Jupyter lab extension and require() only looks for files under the /lib folder and cannot find it.

```
WARNING in ./lib/index.js 41:19-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 
'C:\Users\Username\Documents\github\jupyterlab_extension\lib'
 @ container entry ./extension[0] ./index[0]
```

If I use import, the following error occurs:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\lib'
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2011:28
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:795:13
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:275:22
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:431:22
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:124:11
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:667:25
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:852:8
    at C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:972:5
resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\lib\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/fs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\Matt\Documents\github\py2hex\node_modules\fs doesn't exist
            .js
```

I've included node in tsconfig file:

```
"types": ["node"],
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
```

and have installed `@types/node` using npm install --save @types/node.
Eslint doesn't seem to have a problem with it either after I included "node" in "types" in the tsconfig file, but the compiler just can't pick it up.

Comment: JavaScript extensions run in browser, not in Node - you cannot use node modules like `fs` in the browser as it fortunately does not have access to the local file system. You need to either use jupyter-server contents REST API to retrieve the file or create a server extension and expose the file with a custom endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript extensions run in browser, not in Node - you cannot use node modules like `fs` in the browser as it fortunately does not have access to the local file system. You need to either use [jupyter-server contents REST API](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/rest-api.html) to retrieve the file or create a [jupyter-server extension](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/extensions.html) and expose the file with a custom endpoint.